# .NET: Can BeginAccept() be called before the previous EndAccept() has completed?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

Is the following sequence is legal or should the call to the next BeginAccept() happen only after EndAccept returned ?

```
listener.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, null);

private void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
   listener.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, null); //Is this ok ? Or should happen only after next line?
   socket = listener.EndAccept(ar);

}
```

Comment: Having multiple outstanding accepts is a common usage pattern for the underlying Windows APIs -- I'd be very surprised if this wasn't supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's safe, based on two parts of the documentation for the [Socket class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx):

> If you perform multiple asynchronous operations on a socket, they do not necessarily complete in the order in which they are started.

and

> Instances of this class are thread safe.

That is, the first comment doesn't list any caveats over *which* asynchronous operations it's valid to have multiple of at the same time. And the second comment is much stronger than the usual threading guarantees for classes in the .NET framework.

Comment: *Instances of this class are thread safe* doesnt guarantee that code using it will be thread safe

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - no, but it does imply that one thread can be calling `BeginAccept` no matter what state any other thread may be in - e.g. even if that other thread is in an async callback and hasn't yet called `EndAccept`. Thus, the general principal that you can call `BeginAccept` before an `EndAccept` is established.